# Entity Framework Migration - Alter Table Statement Conflicted with Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a blog of sorts with C#/.NET 4.5 framework using EF code-first migrations.

Things have been going well up until adding a third relationship into my main class.

I have a "story" class (kind of like a "post" for a blog) where I have the author as the user who's logged in (set in the controller), a title, some content, the date it was created, and a genre and type of story.

```
public class Story
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(100), MaxLength(5000)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public StoryType StoryType { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

I added storytypes as a property to the story. StoryType links to the StoryType model:

```
public class StoryType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I made sure to add my dbset to my application db context:

```
public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
public DbSet<StoryType> StoryTypes { get; set; }
```

I pretty much followed the same steps I used to create the relationship between the story and genre (which worked fine). Before I start building the StoryType controllers, I went into package-console and ran:

```
add-migration
```

that returned:

```
 public partial class CreateTypeTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.StoryTypes",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            AddColumn("dbo.Stories", "StoryTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Stories", "StoryTypeId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Stories", "StoryTypeId", "dbo.StoryTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Stories", "StoryTypeId", "dbo.StoryTypes");
            DropIndex("dbo.Stories", new[] { "StoryTypeId" });
            DropColumn("dbo.Stories", "StoryTypeId");
            DropTable("dbo.StoryTypes");
        }
    }
```

Glancing over it, I didn't see an issue, then ran:

```
update-database
```

in package-console.

Which returned:

```
Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Stories_dbo.StoryTypes_StoryTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-HiRatik.Stories-20180724043630", table "dbo.StoryTypes", column 'Id'.
```

I'm not sure what went wrong here. I did the same process with the Genre relationship and it worked. I didn't see a difference in the two.

Comment: Is this the initial migration or an additional one?  I do not see where the tables "Stories" and "Genres" are created.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the StoryTypeId in the class Story dosen't accept null so you need to make the StoryTypeId nullable :

```
public class Story
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(100), MaxLength(5000)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        public int? StoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public StoryType StoryType { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

or you create first the table StoryType and you add elements to it and then add the StoryTypeId with default value:

public class Story
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(100), MaxLength(5000)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [[DefaultValue(1)]]
    public int StoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public StoryType StoryType { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

in this case you must update the database after creating StoryType and the after adding the StoryTypeId to the class Story

Answer (score 0):

You can make the foreign key nullable by using a sign `?`, like this: `int?`.

In my case, I was getting this because there was data in the table on which I was creating the foreign key that's why I was getting this error. And as we know foreign key is nullable.